# How to fetch multiple column values using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am able to fetch the single column value and access that value using controller class but what should do to fetch multiple column values?

DAO method

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Social> getAllSocialData() throws FastestDAOException {
    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("Select social.followers From Social social where social.socialId=1");
        return query.list();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get data"+ex);
}
```

Controller method

```
private static List<QuickStartSocial> followers = null;
public String aBCForm(@ModelAttribute(value = "abcbean") QuickStartBean quickstartbean,Model model) {

try {
followers=quickStartDataService.getAllSocialData();
model.addAttribute("followers",followers);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "quickstart/create";
    }
```

DATABASE

```
ID - socialId
column1 - followers
column2- tweets
```

JSP file

```
<tr>

                            <td>

                                <c:forEach var="in" items="${followers}">

                                         ${in.tweets}

                                </c:forEach>

                            </td>               
                        </tr>
```

I need to fetch suppose followers and "tweets" both from the same Social table in which the data is saved in DB. So what Hibernate Query should I use and how can i access the value of both tweets and following in my controller class?

Comment: Change the query may be to this - `SELECT social.followers, social.tweets FROM Social social WHERE social.socialId=1`? And accordingly change your `List<>` to hold both `follwers` & `tweets`?

Comment: I tried that but it did not worked out

Answer (score -1):

You have several options:

1. return entity

   select social From Social social where social.socialId=1
2. create new DTO and then

   select new SocialDto(social.followers,social.tweets)  From Social social where social.socialId=1
3. map it to list

   Query q = session.createQuery("select social.followers,social.tweets  From Social social where social.socialId=1");

   List employees= (List)q.list();

Comment: i am stroring both columns values in the list but i am not able to access them in the jsp file using <c:forEach>